# Sum of elements of subgroup of $\Bbb Z_p^*$ with order $k$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and $k>1$ a divisor of $p-1$. By [the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups), there is a single subgroup of $\Bbb Z_p^*$ with order $k$. Let $S(p,k)$ be the ordinary (not modular) sum of its elements. For any $g\in\Bbb Z_p^*$ with order $k$, it holds
$$S(p,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(g^i\bmod p)$$
thus
$$\begin{align}
S(p,k)&\equiv\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}g^i&\pmod p\\
&\equiv\frac{g^k-1}{g-1}&\pmod p\\
&\equiv0&\pmod p
\end{align}$$

Define the integer
$$\Delta(p,k)=\frac{S(p,k)}p-\left\lfloor\frac k2\right\rfloor$$

When $k$ is even, $\Delta(p,k)=0$. Proof: $g$ and $h=p-g$ have the same order, thus $\displaystyle 2S(p,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(g^i\bmod p)+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(h^i\bmod p)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}((g^i\bmod p)+(h^i\bmod p))=k\,p$.

For odd $k$, we also often have $\Delta(p,k)=0$. Regardless of $k$, that holds for $p\le19$. But $\Delta(23,11)=-1$,  $\Delta(29,7)=+1$,  $\Delta(47,23)=-2$,  $\Delta(71,35)=-3$,  $\Delta(101,25)=+2$.

**What is known about $\Delta(p,k)$? How can we bound that quantity?**

Comment: That Dirichlet characters are their own Fourier transform plus Pólya-Vinogradov inequality gives a bound $O(p^{1/2}k)$